# Stop and Continue Looping of For Loop In Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

```
for (var x = 0; x < this.selectedFileType[i].count; x++) {
  this.modal.show();     
}
```

I need to open the modal when it comes inside the loop. And after I close the modal it should be continued

Comment: Could you please give us more insight on what you are trying to achieve by this??

Comment: I have a for loop function. inside the array, there is a count. according to the count I need to open the modal. after I close the modal only I need to open the next one

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use event for this purpose? When you hide your modal you can call your function.

```
<div (onHidden)="afterHidden($event)"> </div>
```

And inside your for loop if you save your current position of x then you can continue to your loop.

```
//var x should be declared outside of function
for (; x < this.selectedFileType[i].count; x++) {
  this.modal.show();     
}
```